# Can std::wfstream passed by-reference AND will I be able to use write() and read() properly?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unicode, io, pass-by-reference

I use a self-made error/log-class for my project which is also be able to store/load itself into/from a file. To make it easier for me when handling more objects I want to pass a file stream by-reference to this function which then uses the write/read member of the stream.

Save with:

```
in.open(L"XError.err",std::ios::in | std::ios::out | std::ios::binary | std::ios::trunc);
```

Load with:

```
in.open(L"XError.err",std::ios::in | std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
```

For saving:

```
unsigned int HError::SaveToBufferW(std::wfstream& file)
{
    _ErrorSaveStruct ess = {0};
    ESS.IsUNICODE = true;
    ESS.ItemCount = 9999999;
    file.write((wchar_t*)&ess,sizeof(_ErrorSaveStruct) / sizeof(wchar_t));
    return 0;
}
```

For loading:

```
int HError::LoadFromBufferW(std::wfstream& file)
{
    _ErrorSaveStruct ess = {0};
    file.read((wchar_t*)&ess,sizeof(_ErrorSaveStruct) / sizeof(wchar_t));
    return 0;
}
```

I checked the file and found out that nothing but **whitespaces** is written.
When I read/write a Unicode-string everything works and the string as well is readable in the file.

Edit: here you go

```
 struct _ErrorSaveStruct
{
    unsigned int MsgSize;
    unsigned int TimeSize;
    unsigned int LastErrorSize;
    int ItemCount;
    int errState;
    bool InitMsg;
    bool IsUNICODE;
};
```

Comment: Can we see the definition for _ErrorSaveStruct?  Your code would really only work if _ErrorSaveStruct was a { wchar_t data[big];}  For pretty much anything else, it looks like your code won't work.

Comment: Passing by reference isn't the issue, that will work. The bug is somewhere else.

Comment: @Mooning Duck: what do you mean? if its size can be divided by 2? I already checked that: sizeof(_ErrorSaveStruct == 24).

Comment: What's the point in using wide streams and then accessing them binary? Are you sure the read and write functions work on wchar_t, as whar_t only makes sense for text and not so much for binary operations?

Comment: @Florian: It's confusing that you are attempting binary I/O but you complain that you only see whitespace. What were you expecting to see, numbers? This maybe wrong, but perhaps you don't understand how binary I/O works?

Comment: i could probably use the C IO-functions as well. I tried it in the main() block and it does strange things as well (only one value is stored, the rest overwritten).

Comment: @john: i DO know that its binary but being logic there should be SOMETHING in the file and not just whitespaces

Comment: @Florian: look at the file in a hex editor, and tell us what's actually there.

Comment: 0x0: 00 00 00 00 00 00   ...... (NEXT-Soft Hex-Editor MX). The badbit of wfstream is also set.

Comment: ok, finally found a solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/161852/how-can-i-read-binary-data-from-wfstream

Comment: Florian: So the answer was what?

Comment: sry, havent enough points (there is a 8 hour limit). I simply changed the method using _wfopen and fwrite/fread. I'll post my solution tomorrow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, used another answer to bypass my problem in some way:

```
int main()
{   
HLib::_ErrorSaveStruct Ess = {0};  // just a namespace
Ess.IsUNICODE = true;
Ess.errState = 100;
Ess.ItemCount = 9999;

wchar_t* StringTest[1] = {L"WOORD"};    // same like (wchar_t[5])

FILE* iobuf = NULL;

// create new in binary read-write mode
if (_wfopen_s(&iobuf,L"WTest.err",L"wb+")==0) 
{
        //WRITING BLOCK
    if (fwrite(&Ess,sizeof(Ess),1,iobuf) != 1)  // sizeof_ErrorSaveStruct
        std::cout << "Fail (Reading struct)";

    if (fwrite(StringTest,sizeof(wchar_t) * 5,1,iobuf) != 1) // size = 5 
        std::cout << "Fail (Reading string)";

    // reset content
    SecureZeroMemory(&Ess,sizeof(Ess));
    SecureZeroMemory(StringTest,sizeof(wchar_t)*5);

    fseek(iobuf,0,0); // rewind
    fflush(iobuf);    // flush because you switch from write to read

     /// READING BLOCK
    if (fread(&Ess,sizeof(Ess),1,iobuf) != 1)   // sizeof_ErrorSaveStruct
        std::cout << "Fail (Reading struct)";

    if (fread(StringTest,sizeof(wchar_t) * 5,1,iobuf) != 1) // size = 5 
        std::cout << "Fail (Reading string)";
    fclose(iobuf);
}

return 0;
```

I really learned something about streams and file IO. Thinking of other solutions, i also could have **passed single parameters (int,bool)** to wfstream instead of a whole struct. It would have been possible **as well to use std::fstream with binary flag** set and pass a wchar_t string via write().  Anyway, this solution works well enough for me and I'm really happy about that.